# Can't upload images to WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to upload images via the dashboard but it gives me the following error,

```
Unable to create directory uploads/2015/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

I read forum posts online which guided to change the folder permissions to 777. I did so but the error is still there. Please guide me. Thanks.

Note: I have also updated to the latest version of WordPress but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Go to the uploads directory, and use `chmod 775 uploads -R` to be sure, it's recursive. After that try again. If it not works, give a shot to this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-uploaded-file-permissions/

Answer (score 2):

Many of the people face this problem this is just a permission Issue

****Follow Below Step****

1)Open Ftp by filezilla or any ftp client
2)Right Click on Wp_contnet Folder
3) Change Permissions From 755 TO 777(Please Make Sure That 777  permission to all in side folder's under wp_content)
4) Than Try to Upload File Agin and its'done

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the permission then try this solution :

Please login to the wordpress dashboard ( http://www.domainname.com/wp-admin ) and access the Miscellaneous settings. Find the uploads path specified, it will most likely be specified as:

"/wp-content/uploads/

Change it to read

"wp-content/uploads/

Answer (score 0):

change your wp-content folder's writing permission

Step 1: Open your File Manager and navigate to the file or folder that you need to change.

Step 2: Click on the name of the file or folder.

Step 3: Click on the Change Permissions link in the top menu of the File Manager page.

Step 4: Click on as many check boxes as you require to create the right permission. The permission numbers underneath the check boxes will update automatically.

Step 5: Click on the Change Permissions button when you are ready. The new permission level is saved and the display updated to show the modified file.

Answer (score 0):

Some time when you upload image so this issue arise just try to change  permission level to 744 but select only for directories and  try to change the permission level to 644 this time for files hope this will works for you .